# Is IIS pre-requisite for NLB?

Tags: iis

I have a Java based web app that's hosted on Tomcat. To scale out, I am considering deploying a second virtual server and deploying the web app on it. Also, to ensure that users don't have to worry about changing URL, I am planning to use Microsoft Network load balancer.

I am trying to figure out if IIS is a pre-requisite for NLB. if its not, I would not enable it and hence save myself with managing a port conflict and

Does anyone know if IIs is a pre-requisite for NLB or not?

Comment: When you try to add the NLB Feature, Windows 2008 should tell you what other roles/features you need as prerequisites.  What did it suggest when you added NLB, anything?  Have you read the [NLB documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725691.aspx) yet?

Comment: i dont have a 2008 R2 server without IIS, and don't want to play with prod server that has Tomcat on it. I will have another one and test it out... thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a test today, and IIS is not a pre-requisite to MS NLB.